# MCTS Search Trees for different start States in a Game

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have a fundamental question regarding MCTS. My Question is about the handling of start states.
As far as I understand the Search tree is build by branching for valid actions and that results in the same Search tree being traversed when starting in the same state each time. But what if the start state of a game is different each time the game starts? (e.g. dealt different cards)
Does that result in multiple root Nodes essentially resulting in N different search trees for a game with N possible combinations of dealt cards? Doesn't this mean the Search tree I build in previous games is useless if the start state differs?
How are different start states handled in MCTS?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, MCTS is used for fast approximation of min-max tree. There is no such thing as "different start nodes" here - you run your algorithm **given particular, current state** to find the best answer/move. In card games - you run it once you **see your cards** etc. The "problem" arises in general in non deterministic games where you are not sure about the result of particular move (due to the randomness of the game rules etc.). Such situations are called "non deterministic games" (dice games) or "games with partial information" (like card games). For each there have been developed methods for MCTS.

I suggest taking a look at the http://mcts.ai/ , where you can find great library of MCTS related papers.

Comment: Well I understand that you run your algorithm after you have seen your cards. But that is only theoretical is it not? In an implementation you want to store the tree and use it in future runs to improve it further. It's not like the tree will be reset for everytime you start a new game as The algorithm probably needs more than one game to optimise the tree.

Comment: I think you are confusing two things. If you are trying to build **optimal game strategy** then yes, you will have to store the tree. But it does not matter - you can simply model it as a first, initial state, which has random successors - based on the cards. But in "real life applications", like UCT algorithm for GO you build the tree online, MCTS are based on heavy simulations, which are performed on the base of **current state**. You don't actually "play" moves that are considered in the tree, you simulate them (this is what Monte Carlo is about)

Comment: Now I am really confused. Isn't MCTS trying to simulate roll-Outs and optimising a minmax like tree on the fly? MCTS builds the tree with simulations as long as it is allowed to. In "real Life applications", this tree will be stored and when an action is needed you look up one in the tree, right?

Comment: once action is taken, you cut off unreachable part of the tree and run it once again (updating the current tree), as you *usually) get new resources (turn time). As a result, you always **know** your cards in the **initial** state. As I stated in the answer - game may be underterministic, but the "starting" state is always **known**

Comment: So can you tell me how would you make sure you get better results with each play through(each new game). Wouldn't it make sense to store the big tree build before and merge with trees resulting from multiple playouts? It is not always possible to evaluate all possible playOuts in one simulation phase, is it?

Comment: I already answered this. You can rather store some meta information, heuristic approximations etc. not the tree itself, unless the game is **very repeatable**. But as the MCTS is used mailny for games with **huge branching factor** storing the tree is simply impossible, as the chance that you will visit at least part of already built tree is close to 0. Of course you can store some "opening part" (tree up to some level), but "deeper" nodes are simply useless (or of **very limited value**). MCTS is a **search strategy**, not the machine learning-self improving ai on its own rights.

Comment: Ah I finally understood! Do you know what they did in Go? Did they perform simulations for all possible playOuts? I fathom even bringing one playout to a decisive end would need some amount of time? So the heuristic for selecting actions is quite a heavy factor of good results. Then again I thought no good heuristics were found in Go.